# How to get user roles during checkout and store them as user meta?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

What I a looking for, is to get the user's roles and store them as user meta after the checkout process.

To accomplish that I was trying by using this function:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_user_registration_role', 10, 1 );

function set_user_registration_role( $user_id ) {

$user = wp_get_current_user( $user_id ); // getting & setting the current 
 user 
 $roles = ( array ) $user->roles; // obtaining the role 
// Update the registration meta data
update_user_meta ( $user_id, 'registration_role', $user->user_registered );}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working, I'm getting the user meta "registration_role" but it is empty and not
showing the user's roles.

Is there anyone who could help me with this?

Thanks in advance!